# nlobjFile.getValue does not work in Suitelet

Tags: netsuite

I have used the following code in a NetSuite Suitelet to upload and process a file:

```
function main(request,response){
    if (request.getMethod() == 'GET'){
        var form = nlapiCreateForm('Item Import Correction', false);    
        var fileField = form.addField('custpage_file', 'file', 'Select CSV');                
        form.addSubmitButton();        
        response.writePage(form);        
    }else{
        try{
            var file = request.getFile("custpage_file");
            var content = file.getValue();//exception
            response.write(content);
        }catch(ex){
            response.write('Exception:'+ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

When I select a file and submit it, I get an exception on calling `getValue()` on `nlobjFile`. Here is the output of response:

```
Exception:JavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
```

However, I replace the `getValue()` call with some other method of the same object like `getSize()` or `getType()`, the code works fine.

I just want to parse a file selected by user in a Suitelet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `setEncoding()` method on `nlobjFile` did the trick for me. I was using Chinese Encoding so this was the code that worked for me

```
var file = request.getFile("custpage_file");
file.setEncoding('GB18030');// Chinese
var content = file.getValue();//no exception
```

Answer (score 0):

getFile() - Returns a file added through the nlobjForm.addField(name, type, label, sourceOrRadio, tab) method. When adding a file field type, you will set the type parameter of 'file'.

Make sure that the field you are referencing to using getFile() do exists in the form.

Comment: Checked this stuff. Every thing is in place. Seems like an encoding issue.